# Huge delay while streaming the first video over IP in gstreamer

Tags: udp, video-streaming, streaming, gstreamer, rtp

We are using gstreamer for Video streaming over IP.

On the receiver end I am using the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph2 64depay ! h264parse ! imxvpudec ! imxipuvideosink sync=false
```

On the sender end we are using the following pipeline:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86_64\\bin\\hash.h264 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=<IPAddress> port=5004 sync=true
```

When I am playing the first video, it takes a long time to start playing, more than 5 seconds.

But from the next video, it just starts playing.

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86_64\\bin\\test.h264 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=<IPAddress> port=5004 sync=true
```

Is there a way so the first video also plays instantly without any delay

Comment: Without any details on the files how are supposed to tell? Anyway, the decoder will start playing when it has SPS, PPS and an I-frame. Check your first file if these are included at the beginning of the file.

Comment: The same file when played second time works fine

Comment: May make a difference which you start first, sender or receiver..

Comment: I start receiver first. Should I start sender first??

Comment: No thats fine.. but then it does not rellay explain the non deterministic behavior..